# html button that stays pushed after refresh

Tags: html, button, checkbox, refresh

I am making a site from which I control some electrical devices in the house. I have checkboxes for controlling the devices and a submit form, but after submit the checkboxes appear unchecked. I want a way for them to stay checked after submit and page refreshes. It doesn't have to be necessarily a checkbox... anything that can implement the on-off toggle with memory of previous state is fine. Any suggestions?

(the on-off state of every device is stored in a txt file that updates at every change, if that helps)

Comment: What have you tried so far? You'll also need to use a server-side language (such as PHP, etc.) for this - do you have any experience of these?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i use php and html. i tried using some jave scripts i found online but i didn't have much luck...i'm not realy familiar with javascripts so maybe it was just my fault.

Comment: You simply need to set the checkbox defaults after reading and parsing the text file into PHP. (fget/putcsv and an array being a simple solution.) Have you attempted this or something similar? (If so, please post the code.)

Comment: Do you have any live examples, or code examples of what you currently have that you can post?

Comment: that's exactly what i want...set the checkbox default after reading the txt file. i know how to read it and have variables with the states of every device. i just don't know how to use that in the checkbox form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of what you could do :

First read the value of your text file :

```
<?php
$filename = "/usr/local/something.txt"; // Your file
$handle = fopen($filename, "r");
$contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
fclose($handle);
?>
```

... and then in your form, check the box only if you file has the correct content :

```
<input type="checkbox" name="name" value="Value" <?php echo ($contents == '1' ? 'checked' : '' )?>> Value<br>
```

Of course you have to adapt $contents == '1' to whatever is in your text file when you want it to be checked.